# Ограничить метод класса

Tags: c#

Допустим, есть такой класс:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass
{
  public abstract bool Send<T>(T msg);
}
```

Я хочу произвести наследование:

```
ConcreateClass<T>:AbstractClass
```

Но так, чтоб T ограничивала возле определения класса, ограничила метод абстрактного класса и туда можно было передавать не все подряд, а то с каким параметром типа будет создан класс.

Я могу это сделать?

Потом я хочу это все добавить в словарь Dictionary<Type,AbstractClass> и определяя тип msg передавать его в конкретный обработчик.

Comment: Ну здесь 2 варианта, либо обобщение на классе, это вам не подходит, либо на методе, тогда не будет обобщения на наследнике, либо оно будет никак не связано с методом, либо классический боксинг в какой-нибудь object или необобщенного родителя. `public override bool Send<T>(T msg) where T : ConstraintType { }` Другими словами, обобщенный класс в коллекцию никак не засунуть, так как `MyClass<T1>` и `MyClass<T2>` - это 2 разных типа, как `MyClass1` и `MysClass2`, их можно собрать в коллекцию только имея одного общего необобщенного или обобщенного с конкретным типом родителя.

Answer (score 1):

А зачем собственно абстрактный класс, суйте интерфейс

```
interface ISender
{
  public bool Send<T>(T msg);
}

ConcreateClass<T>:ISender Where T: ....
{
   public bool Send<T>(T msg)
   {
       // Concreate implementation
   }
}
```

Выражение where T: Message в определении метода SendMessage говорит, что через универсальный параметр T будут передаваться объекты класса Message и производных классов. Благодаря этому компилятор будет знать, что T будет иметь функционал класса Message, и соответственно мы сможем обратиться к методам и свойствам класса Message внутри метода без проблем.

Пример как говорится на коленках.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Dictionary<Type, ISender> dic = new Dictionary<Type, ISender>();

    dic.Add( typeof(Dog) , new Dog());

    dic.Add(typeof(Cat), new Cat());

    foreach (var item in dic)
    {
        if (item.Key == typeof(Dog))
            item.Value.Send(new Dog());
        if (item.Key == typeof(Cat))
            item.Value.Send(new Cat());
    }

    Console.Read();

}

public class Dog : ISender
{
    public bool Send<Dog>(Dog msg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(msg.GetType());
        return true;
    }
}

public class Cat : ISender
{
    public bool Send<Cat>(Cat msg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(msg.GetType());

        return true;
    }
}


interface ISender
{
    bool Send<T>(T msg);
}
```

Comment: В этом случае никто не мешает внутри `Cat` написать `Send<Dog>`. Не хорошо, не плохо, просто факт.

Comment: @aepot Да согласен. Не претендую на идеальное решение. про100 как всегда попытка помочь

Comment: И всё же рекомендация использовать интерфейс, нежели наследие

Comment: И чтоб не было проблем можно валидацию воткнуть внутри Send. Тока все это будет в ран там

Answer (score 0):

Инкапсулируй добавление/хранение/извлечение обработчика. Внутри можно хоть в object хранить.

```
public abstract class AbstractSender<T>
{
    public abstract bool Send(T msg);
}

public class Sender
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, object> _senders = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

    public void AddSender<T>(AbstractSender<T> sender)
    {
        _senders.Add(typeof(T), sender);
    }

    public AbstractSender<T> GetSender<T>()
    {
        if (_senders.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out object sender))
        {
            return sender as AbstractSender<T>;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("");
        }
    }
}
```

Тут правильнее на самом деле AbstractSender на интерфейс заменить, но суть та же будет.
После просто регистрируешь нужные сендеры и можно их использовать.

```
public class Cat { }

public class CatSender : AbstractSender<Cat>
{
    public override bool Send(Cat msg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Send Cat");
        return true;
    }
}

public class Dog { }

public class DogSender : AbstractSender<Dog>
{
    public override bool Send(Dog msg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Send Dog");
        return true;
    }
}


var senders = new Sender();
senders.AddSender(new CatSender());
senders.AddSender(new DogSender());

senders.GetSender<Cat>().Send(new Cat());
```